# Redirect to handling page

Tags: asp.net

On the masterpage I have menu items links that look like like:

```
<ul><li><a href=type=article&articleId=82>Article 82</a></li></ul>
```

When the link is clicked, I want to navigate to the right aspx page based on the QueryString 'type' (in this case DisplayArticle.aspx) and pass the parameter to it (in this case articleId=82).

How to do it?

Should I create a special Handler page like HandleRequest.aspx, so the menu item would look like:

```
<ul><li><a href=HandleRequest.aspx?type=article&articleId=82>Article 82</a></li></ul>
```

And then after parsing the QueryString, rediret to a needed page?
Or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: From where do you decide what is going to place on the "type".

Comment: @ Aristos, Do you mean when  I generate the link? if yes, in masterpage's load event.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put in the direct link, use a generic handler (HandleRequest.ashx) and parse your querystrings, yo can then re-use this across your application.

If you are using asp.net MVC, you can use the URL Routing to do something similar which would be cleaner as well.

Good luck

Comment: But how do I redirect to this handler page when link is clicked? 
<a href=HandleRequest.ashx?type=article&articleId=82> ?